# Getting only last value from List<T>

Tags: c#

I have problem with my list because I always get only last value from this list. I don't know how can I fix it... I've tried with override etc but it's doesnt' function or I did this incorrect.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp13
{
    class Program
    {
        static public List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Person person = new Person();
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your name: ");
                person.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Your Surname: ");
                person.Surname = Console.ReadLine();
                personList.Add(person);
            }
            while (personList.Count < 3);

            foreach (Person item in personList) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " " + item.Surname);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're modifying the same instance 3 times. Put the instantiation of the person inside the do while loop like this:

```
...
do
{
    var person = new Person();
    Console.WriteLine("Your name: ");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the person object within loop

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace ConsoleApp13
    {
        class Program
        {
            static public List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
    
                
                do
                {
                    Person person = new Person();//initialize here
                    Console.WriteLine("Your name: ");
                    person.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Surname: ");
                    person.Surname = Console.ReadLine();
                    personList.Add(person);
                }
                while (personList.Count < 3);
    
                foreach (Person item in personList) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " " + item.Surname);
                }
    
    
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    
        class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Person person = new Person();
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your name: ");
                person.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Your Surname: ");
                person.Surname = Console.ReadLine();
                personList.Add(person);
```

When you add a person to personList, it is a reference to person object. It is not a copy of that object. It implies that if You want different objects, You also need to create a new Person Object in each interaction.

```
do
            {
                Person person = new Person();
                Console.WriteLine("Your name: ");
                person.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Your Surname: ");
                person.Surname = Console.ReadLine();
                personList.Add(person);
```

Take a look at references and value type.
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type

Comment: Thanks friend for smooth explain my problem. It's very helpful.